# using power bi platform for python visualization

Tags: python, powerbi-desktop

wanted to use python for importing, arranging the data and introducing it (mathplotlib),
most of the data is over time, and I wanted to provide the visuality to nontechnical users + options to filter the data dynamically, I thought about using the python on power bi platform 
wanted to advise if I'm going on the right path with this?
 and the second thing - I got stocked  right in the beginning, I set everything in PBI as mention here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-python-ide
(I do use the latest anaconda as my only environment)
but getting errors even for the following basic script :

---

import pandas as pd
basedf = pd.read_csv("L:\TECH\Reports\BOMf\temp\baseAll.csv")

---

the error is :
unable to connect 
Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error.
C:\Users\eran_r\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py:140: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in 
    import os, pandas, matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\eran_r\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 17, in 
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\eran_r\Anaconda3\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

"